# What is the worst case time complexity of sorting an array of strings using sort() function in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

Example

```
string input[3]={"Earth","Mars","Mercury"};
sort(input,input+3);
```

Comment: This depends on your implementation. Can you specify please?

Comment: I'm talking about sort function, the one provided in STL

Comment: Yes I know, and this depends on your implementation. The one from MS is different from the one from gcc, clang, Intel, ...

Comment: Each standard library implementation is free to implement the standard algorithms in any way it sees fit, provided it respect the requirements set by the c++ standard. The standard demands `O(n log(n))` comparison complexity for `std::sort` and a few other technical details. Beyond that, the exact implementation details are not defined and vary from platform to platform. They can even vary from version to version or compiler flag to compiler flag.

Comment: You can easily find this kind of information at https://en.cppreference.com

Answer (score 3):

Until C++11, the complexity is `N.log(N)` on average, and the worst case complexity depends on your standard library implementation. For later versions of the language, the standard requires the complexity to be exactly `N.log(N)`.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort:

> #### Complexity
>
> *O(N·log(N))*, where `N = std::distance(first, last)` comparisons on average. (until C++11)
>   *O(N·log(N))*, where `N = std::distance(first, last)` comparisons. (since C++11)

Comment: I guess that means no one can use Quick sort  anymore as a valid implementation.  It's nice that they got rid of the *on average* part.

Comment: @NathanOliver, that is nice indeed.

Comment: In the case of Visual Studio, std::sort is a variation of [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), with worst case time complexity O(n log(n)), but the check and transition into heap sort make it slower than a pure quick sort on "average" case data like psuedo random data, which is unlikely to produce poor pivot choices.